# Package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project

Tags: .net-core, nuget, ui-automation

I use UIAutomationClient.dll in a Framework project which I'm moving to Core.  This will only be on Windows so it's OK.  But I need to reference it in way that can be run on differenet windows machines.  There is a nuget package for this, commented that it should not be referenced directly.  So how do I get it?  If I go ahead and choose it, I get the error:

*package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project*

Please note: this is a console application which does some UI automating.  It's not a desktop app, not WPF.

[image]

Comment: "There is a nuget package for this", any source to prove that you need this?

Comment: Not sure of your question.  The package exists. I need it because the code uses it.

Comment: My question is "why do you think that NuGet package should be used". What code will ever use it when Microsoft clearly says not?

Comment: Ah, I see. Right now I use a simple dll reference, relying that the file is on the filesystem.  In fact, I've made sure it is on the deploy servers so things work fine now.  But what I'd like to know is - should these come from nuget instead?  It seems safer to me than pure dll references.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3283#issuecomment-532857465 Based on the comment, you should need to use the right SDK.

Answer (score 13):

[As vatsan-madhavan wrote on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3283#issuecomment-570483730), you can use:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Wpf" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Learning from all the problems with the BCL packages in .NET Core 1.x and 2.x, starting from .NET Core 3.0, the .NET Core SDK and NuGet support `FrameworkReference`, which does not use version numbers (the SDK tells NuGet which version to download). Since it's so new, it's not well known, or frequently documented.